# Fibonacci numbers, how to find the number (java)

Tags: java, math, fibonacci

I've got the task to find the index of the first non-zero member of Fibonacci list, which is evenly divisible by this some value (in my example below the values are: 17 12 61). So I created the Fibonacci sequence, go through that sequence dividing each member and check the remainder for zero:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String stringInputValues = "17 12 61";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(stringInputValues);

    int i = 0;
    BigInteger value = BigInteger.ZERO;;

    //start create Fibonacci numbers
    int N = 9000;
    BigInteger[] fibArray = new BigInteger[N + 1];
    fibArray[0] = BigInteger.ZERO;
    fibArray[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        fibArray[i] = fibArray[i - 1].add(fibArray[i - 2]);

    }
    //end create Fibonacci numbers
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        value = BigInteger.valueOf(scan.nextLong());
        for (i = 0; i <= fibArray.length - 1; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && fibArray[i].remainder(value) == BigInteger.ZERO) {

                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work for big values (the numbers so big that I got **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**) of divider, for example **233328 433156 1032566** instead of **17 12 61**
I feel my algorithm is too simple and inefficient. Could you help me with more effective one?
Thanks!

Comment: What about it doesn't work? It just takes too long? This probably belongs on  [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes. The numbers very big and I got the message: 
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

Comment: you don't have a stopping condition is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve your problem be increasing the heap space with an JVM command. But still your program is such a memory hog, in other words highly inefficient. Such as

```
java -Xmx256m MyProgram.java
```

setting maximum heap space of `256m`.

I would suggest you, checking for the remainder while creating the Fibonacci numbers. That way you would never create more than what you need. And to ensure that you don't use too much heap when there are no appropriate dividers, use a stopping condition.

**Note**: `BigInteger` uses something like `4N + 64Bytes` for a number N. That is because it is stored internally as `int[]` and each int is defined in JAVA to be `4 Bytes`.

But still the 9000th Fibonacci number would be huge..

---

*EDIT(2):*
It would take 196 ints to represent the 9000th Fibonacci number, because the 9000th Fibonacci number needs 6248 bits to be represented. Since each int in Java is 4 Bytes then we will end up with `784 + 64 = 848 Bytes` for the int[] ≡ BigInteger number. Which is almost a 1KB.

Comment: Yep. Agree. I'm looking for algorithm, could you please describe efficient algorithm for this task?

Comment: Woah -- How did you calculate how many bites that number would require?

Comment: Bytes not bits (if not typo). Well, first I turn a BigInteger into #bytes and then convert it to YB.

Comment: Not sure your logic is correct; my code went out to the 1548851th Fibonacci number and did not hit a memory exception.  (My machine does not have a YB of memory)

Comment: @BrianRisk yes, you are absolutely right, I fixed it. I was not converting it properly to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to compute the Fibonacci numbers one at a time.  This solution has a method which returns the index of the Fibonacci number evenly divisible by the argument:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class FibonacciDivider {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int [] input = {233328, 433156, 1032566};
        for (int val: input) {
            System.out.println("index of Fibo. num. divisible by " + val +
                    ": " +  findIndexOfFibonacciWithDivisor(BigInteger.valueOf(val)));
        }
    }

    public static int findIndexOfFibonacciWithDivisor(BigInteger divisor) {
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            index++;
            BigInteger c = b.add(a);
            // the mod() method returns the remainder
            if (c.mod(divisor).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) return index;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
    }
}
```

The output (so far!) is:

```
index of Fibo. num. divisible by 233328: 1619
index of Fibo. num. divisible by 433156: 281
```

It's still cranking on 1032566!

UPDATE: `index of Fibo. num. divisible by 1032566: 1548851`

Answer (score 0):

9000th Fibonacci number is quite big. Probably, it's enough memory to generate 9000 of them but `BigInteger` division is heavy operation and could take a lot of memory (and time).

Introduce `Iterator` instead of generating 9000 numbers. Maybe, there are some mathematical tricks related to Fibonacci numbers divisibility.

If you don't have to output number itself but only want to tell if it exists, you have to employ modular arithmetic and avoid `BigInteger`s at all. Just compute moduli of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Well, I thought about modular arithmetic, but have no idea how to realize it.

Comment: @SergeyLotvin Easy: just keep moduli, not full numbers. Keep in mind that `(a + b) % m == a % m + b % m`. Use `int`s or `long`s and take moduli after each operation. In your case, `F[i] = (F[i-1] + F[i-2]) % m;`. And then just simply compare moduli to zero.

Comment: @SergeyLotvin I just reread statement. It was intended to make you use modular arithmetic.